# Excel - Concatenate Cells Between Two Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get all the years in between (and including) two cells indicating the start year and the end year

Such that if 2018 is the start and 2022 is the year, I'm wanting to return 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022

Likewise if 2015 was the start and 2017 was the end, return 2015 2016 2017

What would be the best way to go about this?

[image]

Comment: Does your version of Excel support TEXTJOIN?

Comment: Yes it does! Using O365

Comment: @JvdV - good find, oops, I should have looked for a  dupe first.

Comment: @bigben no drama, we answer tons of questions with dupes. This one just so happen to be the very first hit on Google. Thought as well I might close it.

Comment: @JvdV thank you, I kind of suspected it was probably a dupe but didn't know what to search for to find it

Answer (score 3):

Using `TEXTJOIN` and `SEQUENCE`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,SEQUENCE(C5-C4+1,,C4))
```

[image]

Comment: Sir very nice & sleek, here is one more way `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,SEQUENCE(,C5-C4+1,C4))` & this one as well, `=TRIM(CONCAT(" "&SEQUENCE(,C5-C4+1,C4)))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - correct, one can create rows or columns with the sequence, TEXTJOIN handles either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing this along to other users I would add a check to make sure the dates are entered in the correct order.

```
=IF(C5>=C4,TEXTJOIN(" ",,SEQUENCE(C5-C4+1,,C4)),"Enter the start date in the first cell")
```

Answer (score -1):

Wasn't familiar with `textjoin` so I wrote a macro.

```
Sub years()

Dim beginyr As Integer
Dim endyr As Integer
Dim diff As Integer
Dim addyr As Integer
Dim arrYears(99) As String

With ActiveSheet

    beginyr = .Cells(3, 1)
    endyr = .Cells(4, 1)
    diff = endyr - beginyr
    addyr = 0
    
    For i = 0 To diff
        arrYears(i) = beginyr + addyr
        addyr = addyr + 1
    Next
    
    c = 2
    For Each e In arrYears()
        .Cells(5, c) = e
        c = c + 1
    Next

End With

End Sub
```